# Requesting a robust regex that checks if an img tag contains the alt element in a HTML document

Tags: python, html, regex, validation, logging

I'm writing a python script to check a HTML documents IMG tags. 
It should check that alt="" is present inside of the IMG tag.
It would then print out the line number.

The regex would have to factor in different order of contents. EG:

```
<img class="" alt="" src="">
<img class="" src="">
<img src="" class="">
<img src="">
```

so yes, to summerise. 
regex to check that all of the elements of the img tag are present
it must account for a range of possible arrangements

Thank you

Comment: You first state your question as solely about the alt element but then you say you want to 'check that all of the elements of the img tag are present it must account for a range of possible arrangements'. It's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: `<img(?=\s)(?=(?:[^>"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*?\salt\s*=\s*(?:(['"])\s*([\S\s]*?)\s*\1))\s+(?:"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|[^>]*?)+>` The content of the alt is in capture group 2 if needed. http://regex101.com/r/AFMhoX/1

Answer (score 2):

Using regexes to evaluation HTML is a bit risky, but if you're willing to accept the shortcomings*, you could get this to work using [positive lookahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
regex = re.compile(r'<img (?=[^>]*\balt=")(?=[^>]*\bsrc=")(?=[^>]*\bclass=")')
```

will match if the current string contains `<img` that's followed (within the same tag) by `alt="`, `src="` and `class="`, in any order.

**Explanation:**

```
<img    # Match '<img'
(?=     # Assert that it's possible to match the following from this position:
 [^>]*  #  Any number of characters except >
 \b     #  A word boundary (here: start of a word)
 alt="  #  The literal text 'alt="'
)       # End of lookahead
(?=[^>]*\bsrc=")   # Do the same for `src`, from the same position as before
(?=[^>]*\bclass=") # Do the same for `class`, from the same position as before
```

<sub>*Of course this regex is completely ignorant as to whether the tag it's matching is within a comment, interrupted by a comment, malformed, surrounded by `<pre>` tags or any other situation that might change its meaning to an actual HTML parser.</sub>

Comment: For what it's worth: All of the noted shortcomings should do nothing but reinforce the fact that regex ain't for parsin'. To work around all of that - lxml, beautifulsoup, or even pyxml are the REAL solution.

Comment: +1 But Tim - If you're going to go the extra mile to fully comment the regex, (which should be done for all non-trivial regexes such as this one), why not just write the regex in free-spacing mode in the first place? Its less work for you and you'll be setting a good example of best practices at the same time. (JavaScrict excepted)